# oninput event is not working in Rails form

Tags: ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to add oninput event in rails form using ajax call.I added it but its not working.I also want when input field will get the data the form will submit and result will come in the same page without reloading the page.I am explaining my code below.

## homes/home.html.erb

```
<%= form_for :sdf ,:url => {:action => "scan_report" },remote: true do |f| %>
    <% if params[:receipt_no] %>
    <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12"> <span class="input-group-addon text-left">Receipt No. Scan :</span>
        <%= f.text_field :Receipt_No,:class => "form-control", :value => params[:receipt_no],oninput => "this.form.submit();"  %>
    </div>
    <% else %>
    <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12"> <span class="input-group-addon text-left">Receipt No. Scan :</span>
        <%= f.text_field :Receipt_No,:class => "form-control",placeholder:"Receipt No. scan" %>
    </div>
    <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

The above input field will get value when user will click on view action of table which is given below.

## reports/view_report.html.erb

```
<div class="block-content">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
        <colgroup>
            <col class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
            <col class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
            <col class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
            <col class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
            <col class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
            <col class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
            <col class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
        </colgroup>
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <th class="text-center">Sl. No</th>
            <th class="text-center">Receipt Number</th>
            <th class="text-center">Date</th>
            <th class="text-center">Deceased Name</th>
            <th class="text-center">Deceased Adress</th>
            <th class="text-center">Doner Name</th>
            <th class="text-center">Doner Adress</th>
            <th class="text-center">Doner Mobile No</th>
            <th class="text-center">Doner's Relationship</th>
            <th class="text-center">Donation Amount</th>
            <th class="text-center">Date of death</th>
            <th class="text-center">HCSY Status</th>
            <th class="text-center">Deceased photo</th>
            <th class="text-center">Doner photo</th>
            <th class="text-center">Brahmin</th>
            <th class="text-center">Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <% @sdf.each do |sdf| %>
        <tr>
        <td class="text-center"><%= sdf.Sdp_Id %></td>
         <td class="text-center"><%= sdf.Receipt_No %></td>
        <td class="text-center"><%= sdf.Created_On %></td>
        <td class="text-center"><%= sdf.Deceased_Name %></td>
        <td class="text-center"><%= sdf.Deceased_Address1 %></td>
        <td class="text-center"><%= sdf.Doner_Name %></td>
        <td class="text-center"><%= sdf.Doner_Address1 %></td>
        <td class="text-center"><%= sdf.Doner_MobileNo %></td>
        <td class="text-center"><%= sdf.Doner_Relationship_Other %></td>
        <td class="text-center"><%= sdf.Donation_Amount %></td>
        <td class="text-center"><%= sdf.Date_Of_Death %></td>
        <td class="text-center"><%= sdf.HCSY_Status %></td>
        <td class="text-center"><%= image_tag(sdf.Photo,:width => 50,:height => 50) %></td>
        <td class="text-center"><%= image_tag(sdf.Doner_Photo,:width => 50,:height => 50) %></td>
        <td class="text-center"><%= sdf.Brahmin %></td>
        <td class="text-center">
        <div class="btn-group">
        <a href="/homes/home/?receipt_no=<%= sdf.Receipt_No %>" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" class="btn btn-xs btn-success" data-original-title="View">
            <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
        </a>
        </div>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <% end %>
        </tbody>
        </table>
         <%= will_paginate @sdf %>  
    </div>
</div>
```

My other files are given below.

## controller/homes_controller.rb

```
class HomesController < ApplicationController
    def home
        @sdf=TSdf.new
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html
          format.js
        end
    end
    def scan_report
           if @sdf=TSdf.find_by_Receipt_No(params[:sdf][:Receipt_No])
                @hcsy=THcsy.find_by_Sdp_Id(@sdf.Sdp_Id)
                @hcsy_deatils=THcsyDetails.find_by_HCSY_ID(@hcsy.id)
                @woods=THcsyFundTypeMaster.find_by_Fund_Type_Code(1)
                @burn=THcsyFundTypeMaster.find_by_Fund_Type_Code(2)
                @good=THcsyFundTypeMaster.find_by_Fund_Type_Code(3)
                @swd=THcsyFundTypeMaster.find_by_Fund_Type_Code(5)
                @photo=THcsyFundTypeMaster.find_by_Fund_Type_Code(6)
                flash[:notice]=" number matched"
            else
                splitted = params[:sdf][:Receipt_No].split('/')
                receipt = splitted[0]
                table_id = splitted[1]
                @sdfs=TSdf.find_by_Receipt_No(receipt)
                if @sdfs
                    @hcsys=THcsy.find_by_Sdp_Id(@sdfs.Sdp_Id)
                    @fund_details=THcsyFundTypeMaster.find_by_Fund_Type_Code(table_id)
                else
                    flash[:notice]="Scan number not found"
                end
            end
    end
end
```

## scan_report.js.erb

```
$("#whole-div1").css("display", "block");
$("#whole-div").css("display", "block");
$("#whole-div3").css("display", "block");
$("#whole-div4").css("display", "block");
$("#whole-div5").css("display", "block");
$("#whole-div6").css("display", "block");
$("#whole-div8").css("display", "block");
$(".flash-message").html('<%= escape_javascript flash[:notice] %>');
$("#sdf-puri").html("<%= escape_javascript (render 'sdf_output_table' ) %>");
$("#sdf-puri").slideDown(350);
$("#hcsy-puri").html("<%= escape_javascript (render 'hcsy_output_table' ) %>");
$("#hcsy-puri").slideDown(350);
$("#good-puri").html("<%= escape_javascript (render 'goods' ) %>");
$("#good-puri").slideDown(350);
$("#swd-puri").html("<%= escape_javascript (render 'swd' ) %>");
$("#swd-puri").slideDown(350);
$("#burn-puri").html("<%= escape_javascript (render 'burning' ) %>");
$("#burn-puri").slideDown(350);
$("#wood-puri").html("<%= escape_javascript (render 'woods' ) %>");
$("#wood-puri").slideDown(350);
$("#photo-puri").html("<%= escape_javascript (render 'photo' ) %>");
$("#photo-puri").slideDown(350);
```

Please help me to add this type of feature and its very important that result should come the same page without reloading the page.

Comment: I do not understand. What should trigger submitting the form? and then you want the form submitted without a page reload?

Comment: @Ablin,Check the table present in the view_report.html.erb it has one view option.When user will click view option it will redirect to home.html.erb with receipt_no as query string and in home page text field value will set.As soon as text filed value will set the form should submit and result will come in same home page.

Comment: @Albin,Do you have any idea about this.?